# Read Parameters from Hudson Job by Junit Tests

Tags: junit, hudson

In my Maven project, I had some JUnit Tests.
That maven project was build through a Hudson Job which uses Parameters.

Is there a way which Junit pick those Parameters passed in Hudson Job and use them as variables while executing the tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you access parameters like java parameters .. when entering parameters with -Dblubb=xyz then you can access it in the junit run with System.getProperty("blubb", "abc"); in case you enter the parameter "blubb" it gets the String xyz.